# How to stop matching at first the match in end of pattern?

Tags: regex

I have a code like this:

```
super dooper pooper but dooper super pooper
```

I need to match everything from `super` to `pooper` (which can include ALL chars) but stop at the first `pooper`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if I would be a better or worse engineer today if I could have posted all of my problem set questions for someone else to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said in the comments: `/super.*?pooper/` will do the trick if you don't care about matching across lines. If you need to match across lines (and you said in the comments that you do), then you need this:

```
/super.*?pooper/s
```

This means:

- `/` = delimiter
- `super` = match `super`
- `.*?` = match zero or more characters in a "non-greedy" fashion (stop as soon as possible)
- `pooper` = match `pooper`
- `/` = delimiter
- `s` = let `.` match new line characters (`\n`)

[**Here's a demo**](https://regex101.com/r/yU4bQ9/2).

Comment: But there is can be new lines. Thats the problem

Comment: Ah. That is key information. Please see my updated answer. Adding `s` at the end will fix this. Depending on your language, you may also be able to do `/(?s)super.*?pooper/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
super[\s\S]*?pooper

super  ... Match super
[\s\S] ... Match a single character that is a whitespace character or
           match a single character that is not a whitespace character (all characters).
*?     ... Between zero and unlimmited times as few times as possible.
pooper ... Match pooper
```